# FreeBSD: mariadb55 conflicts mysql55

Tags: mysql, mariadb, freebsd

I'm trying to install `percona-toolkit` as package/port on my system:

```
[root@alexus ~]# uname -a
FreeBSD alexus.org 9.2-RELEASE-p5 FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE-p5 #0 r265974: Wed May 14 07:57:04 PDT 2014     root@jj3.myibay.com:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/R610  amd64
[root@alexus ~]# pkg install percona-toolkit
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
Checking integrity... done (1 conflicting)
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
The following 7 packages will be affected (of 0 checked):

Installed packages to be REMOVED:
    mariadb55-client-5.5.39
    mariadb55-server-5.5.39

New packages to be INSTALLED:
    percona-toolkit: 2.2.11
    p5-Term-ReadKey: 2.32
    p5-DBI: 1.631
    p5-DBD-mysql: 4.028
    mysql55-client: 5.5.40

The operation will free 100 MB.

Proceed with this action? [y/N]: n
[root@alexus ~]# cd /usr/ports/databases/percona-toolkit/ && make config
===> No options to configure
[root@alexus /usr/ports/databases/percona-toolkit]#
```

I do *NOT* wish to remove and/or replace my existing `mariadb55-client` and/or `mariadb55-server` with `mysql55-client`.

What should I do?

Comment: Complain to Percona? or whoever built the package.

Comment: @MichaelHampton turns out to be `p5-DBD-mysql` that caused that, but I was able to install `percona-toolkit` anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `p5-DBD-mysql` was the one at "fault":

```
[root@alexus /usr/ports/databases/percona-toolkit]# pkg install p5-DBD-mysql
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
Checking integrity... done (1 conflicting)
Checking integrity... done (0 conflicting)
The following 4 packages will be affected (of 0 checked):

Installed packages to be REMOVED:
    mariadb55-client-5.5.39
    mariadb55-server-5.5.39

New packages to be INSTALLED:
    p5-DBD-mysql: 4.028
    mysql55-client: 5.5.40

The operation will free 107 MB.

Proceed with this action? [y/N]: n
[root@alexus /usr/ports/databases/percona-toolkit]#
```

yet I was able to install it anyway using:

```
[root@alexus /usr/ports/databases/percona-toolkit]# make -C WITH_MYSQL_VER=55m install
...
...
...
===>  Installing for percona-toolkit-2.2.11
===>  Checking if percona-toolkit already installed
===>   Registering installation for percona-toolkit-2.2.11
[root@alexus /usr/ports/databases/percona-toolkit]# echo "WITH_MYSQL_VER=55m" >> /etc/make.conf 
[root@alexus /usr/ports/databases/percona-toolkit]#
```